# Unique array in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I found that it could be done like this:

```
var someSchema = new Schema({
    myArray: [ObjectId], //array of ObjectIds
});

someSchema.index({myArray: 1}, {unique:true});
```

But this code is not working for me. So basically what I am trying to do is to create a **combination** of ObjectIds that may not be duplicated later.

For example:

```
If myArray is [val1, val2] 
Another document with myArray[val1, val2] or myArray[val2, val1] is not allowed
But of course myArray[val1, val3] is allowed, because it is another combination
```

--
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not have an innate index type that will require unique values in each array member.

Instead, use the [$addToSet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSetand%24each) update operator to ensure only one copy of each ObjectID can be added.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way you could use an index to ensure uniqueness in that way would be to use a middleware to ensure that the array is ordered before it is saved, but that may not fit your use case.

If that suits you, you would need to do something like:

```
someSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  this.myArray.sort();
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to create hash of the array and make it unique.

A.e.

```
var someSchema = new Schema({
   myArray: [ObjectId], //array of ObjectIds
   hash: {type: string, unique: true} 
});
```

and then

```
someSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  this.myArray.sort();
  this.hash = this.myArray.toString(); // Simple way. You should use something more practical
  next();
});
```